# Start and End Position of symbols in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find the start and end position of `_` in a string as list of tuples.

The code I used is

```
sentence = 'special events _______ ______ ___ _______ ____ _____ _______ ___________ brochure subscriptions ticket guide'
symbol = '_'

position = [(match.start(),match.end()) for match in re.finditer(symbol, sentence)]
```

For this the output obtained is

```
[(15, 16), (16, 17), (17, 18), (18, 19), (19, 20)..................]
```

How to get the start and end position of continuous located symbols as a list of tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `+` quantifier. And since symbol could be a special symbol for the regular expression you might want to escape it with `re.escape`.

```
import re

sentence = 'special events _______ ______ ___ _______ ____ _____ _______ ___________ brochure subscriptions ticket guide'
symbol = '_'

needle = f'{re.escape(symbol)}+'
position = [(match.start(),match.end()) for match in re.finditer(needle, sentence)]
print(position)
```

The result is `[(15, 22), (23, 29), (30, 33), (34, 41), (42, 46), (47, 52), (53, 60), (61, 72)]`.

Please be aware that `end` is the position after the match as stated in the documentation for [`Match.end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please upvote the question too

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
sentence2 = ' ' + sentence[:-1]
starts = [i for i in range(len(sentence))if sentence[i] == '_' and sentence2[i] != '_' ]
ends = [i - 1 for i in range(len(sentence)) if sentence2[i] == '_' and sentence[i] != '_']
pairs = list(zip(starts, ends))
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
[(15, 21), (23, 28), (30, 32), (34, 40), (42, 45), (47, 51), (53, 59), (61, 71)]
```

This will give the index of the first and last instances of symbol in a substring of one or more contiguous symbol characters. If you need results that use python slice semantics (start == index of first instance of symbol in a contiguous substring, end == index immediately following the last instance of symbol in that substring), you can change `i - 1` to `i` in the initialization line for `ends`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer instead of mine, but I rolled it back. It was an `OutOfCoffeeError` on my side.